# How to specify server-side S3 encryption via ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Through paperclip I was able to specify server side encryption for S3, and also specify a content type (for a wonky file) like this:

```
  has_attached_file :attachment,
    s3_permissions: :private,
    s3_server_side_encryption: 'AES256',
    s3_headers: lambda { |attachment|
       {
         'content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-16le'
       }
     }
```

Where would I specify similar when using `has_attached_one` in ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Active Storage's [S3Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L21), there's upload options are passed transparently from the `upload` key to the [`Aws::S3::Object#put`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method) method. This is also true for Rails 5.2.

So you just need to specify `server_side_encryption` key in your `storage.yml` this way:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: mybucket
  * other properties *
  upload:
    server_side_encryption: "AES256"
```